# Matrix scale/translate from point

Tags: javascript, css, math, matrix

I'm attempting to scale an image and have it translate correctly from an origin point (basically a pinch to zoom). I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve changing `transform-origin`, because it will complicate finding the left/top edges of the picture, which I'm using for more than just this problem.

This is more of a math problem. **I'm having trouble coming up with an equation to determine how much to translate the image, based on an origin. The current equation I have worked out does not scale from a point correctly.** In regards to the demo, the image should *blow up* from the mouse pointer when scrolling with the mouse.

I'm not looking for a workaround, or an alternative design. As stated before, I can't modify the transform-origin property.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dook/ort0efjd/

Matrix transform function

```
function transform() {
  var matrix = [dim.new_scale, 0, 0, dim.new_scale, dim.new_x, dim.new_y].join(",");

  image_center.css({
    "transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-webkit-transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-moz-transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
  });
}
```

Mousewheel event

```
// Determine mousewheel pointer in relation to picture origin
var offset = image_center.offset();
var originX = ev.originalEvent.pageX - offset.left;
var originY = ev.originalEvent.pageY - offset.top;

// truncated --- new_scale is modified

// Translate based on pointer origin -- This is where I need help
dim.new_x = originX + dim.height * (dim.new_scale - 1);
dim.new_y = originY + dim.height * (dim.new_scale - 1);

// truncated -- Keep image within constraints

transform(); // Applies everything in dim to CSS transform matrix
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The JSFiddle seems to work in some ways.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly it is that's not working?

Comment: I updated the question to (hopefully) make my problem clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach is to create an off-screen object and center it's transform-origin. Apply the scaling to this object.

Then copy the Matrix transformation from the off-screen element to the on screen element and you should have the correct scale.

Here are some image prototypes to copy the matrix:

```
HTMLImageElement.prototype.getMatrix = function() {
    var st = window.getComputedStyle(this, null);
    return st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
        'none';
};

HTMLImageElement.prototype.setMatrix = function(matrix) {
    this.style.webkitTransform = 
    this.style.msTransform = 
    this.style.MozTransform = 
    this.style.OTransform = 
    this.style.transform = 
         matrix;
  return this;
};
```

`getMatrix` returns a matrix string.
`setMatrix` takes a matrix string.

```
targetImage.setMatrix(sourceImage.getMatrix())
```

were targetImage is the displayed image
and sourceImage is the off-screen image

Answer (score 1):

I got a partial solution. I think it does what you want, zoom in and out on a point specified by your mouse. Unfortunately, if you zoom, then move your mouse to a different point, then zoom again, it jumps around.

```
var image_center = $("#image");
var base_image = $(".outer");
var dim = {};
var original_offset = image_center.offset();

function resetDim() {
  // Initialize image.dim with values
  dim.cont_width = base_image.width(); // Container width
  dim.cont_height = base_image.height(); // Container height
  dim.width = image_center.width(); // Element width
  dim.height = image_center.height(); // Element height

  dim.new_x = 0; // Initial/new x position
  dim.new_y = 0; // Initial/new y position
  dim.new_scale = 1; // Initial/new scale
  dim.max_scale = 3; // Max image scale
};

function transform() {
  var matrix = [dim.new_scale, 0, 0, dim.new_scale, dim.new_x, dim.new_y].join(",");

  image_center.css({
    "transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-webkit-transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-moz-transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  resetDim();

  $('.outer').bind('mousewheel', function(ev) {
    // onScroll start
    // Determine pointer origin in relation to picture
    var originX = ev.originalEvent.pageX - original_offset.left;
    var originY = ev.originalEvent.pageY - original_offset.top;

    // onScroll ev
    dim.new_scale += (ev.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) ? -0.1 : 0.1;
    if (dim.new_scale > dim.max_scale) dim.new_scale = dim.max_scale;
    else if (dim.new_scale < 1) dim.new_scale = 1;

    // Translate based on origin
    dim.new_x = -(originX * (dim.new_scale-1) );
    dim.new_y = -(originY * (dim.new_scale-1) );

    transform();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: https://jsfiddle.net/6c585qom/2/

Of course, if you scroll too fast, the transitions don't keep up, but if you scroll slowly, the image stays locked to the mouse.

```
var image_center = $("#image");
var base_image = $(".outer");
var dim = {};

function resetDim() {
  // Initialize image.dim with values
  dim.cont_width = base_image.width(); // Container width
  dim.cont_height = base_image.height(); // Container height
  dim.width = image_center.width(); // Element width
  dim.height = image_center.height(); // Element height

  dim.left_edge = 0;
  dim.top_edge = 0; // Edge translation
  dim.init_x = 0;
  dim.new_x = 0; // Initial/new x position
  dim.init_y = 0;
  dim.new_y = 0; // Initial/new y position
  dim.init_scale = 1;
  dim.new_scale = 1; // Initial/new scale
  dim.max_scale = 3; // Max image scale
};

function transform() {
  var matrix = [dim.new_scale, 0, 0, dim.new_scale, dim.new_x, dim.new_y].join(",");

  image_center.css({
    "transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-webkit-transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-moz-transform": "matrix(" + matrix + ") translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  resetDim();
  transform();

  $('.outer').bind('mousewheel', function(ev) {
    // onScroll start
    // Determine pointer origin in relation to picture
    var offset = image_center.offset();
    var originX = ev.originalEvent.pageX - offset.left;
    var originY = ev.originalEvent.pageY - offset.top;
    // Calculate current size of the image.
    var width = dim.width * dim.new_scale;
    var height = dim.height * dim.new_scale;
        // Calculate the relative position of the mouse independent of current scale.
    var mx = originX / width;
    var my = originY / height;

    // onScroll ev
    dim.new_scale += (ev.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) ? -0.1 : 0.1;
    if (dim.new_scale > dim.max_scale) dim.new_scale = dim.max_scale;
    else if (dim.new_scale < 1) dim.new_scale = 1;

    // Update new image position based upon new scale.
    var new_width = dim.width * dim.new_scale;
    var new_height = dim.height * dim.new_scale;
    var new_mouse_x = new_width * mx;
    var new_mouse_y = new_height * my;
    dim.new_x += originX - new_mouse_x;
    dim.new_y += originY - new_mouse_y;
    transform();
  });
});
```